# cocos2d 2.x iphone 4 frame rate drop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I recently ported a project from Cocos2d 1.1 to 2.0. So far everything is working great, but I've noticed that the frame rate drops from 60 fps to around 40-50 fps on the iPhone 4 and the iPod Touch 4. Other devices I have tried (iPads 1 & 3, iPhone 4s) still run at 60.

At first I thought I had too many draw calls, but after reducing the calls from 54 to 17, I still had the same fps on both devices. I should note that I don't have this problem on the default Hello World template, nor do I have any openGL errors in the console. My memory footprint is around 50mb, so I don't think that's the problem either. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the app on the simulator or the actual device?

Comment: Actual device. Simulator has an even larger frame rate drop, but I'm not too worried about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a simple performance problem. The other devices running at 60 fps (at least iPad 3 and iPhone 4S) have more computing power and better graphics processors than the iPhone 4 and iPod Touch 4.

Since this happened after upgrading from cocos2d 1.1 to 2.0, there's the possibility that the 4th generation iPhone devices don't run OpenGL ES 2.0 code (shaders) as fast as the other devices. It could also be an issue with cocos2d 2.0 itself. Unless you really need to use a feature of cocos2d 2.0 (ie shaders) the easiest approach would be to simply go back to cocos2d 1.1. If you aren't writing shaders, cocos2d v1.1 is just the same as 2.0 in terms of features (at this point in time).

Finally, test performance only with release builds. If you run Debug builds things like logging and assertions can totally skew any performance results.

Comment: I found out it only does this if I have two large sprites rendering at the same time, in this case two backgrounds. Only one background and it runs at 6o fps again.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Know of any way to easily downgrade from cocos2d 2.0 to 1.x?